# Listing Inbox with Javamail API

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, inbox

I'm getting inbox folder of my gmail account, can list the incoming e-mails, but that list is being listed from older mails to newer mails. How can i revert that ?

```
    public class readInbox extends ListActivity{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//setContentView(R.layout.readmail);

Message[] messages = new Message[] { };

try {
    messages = inboxReader.getMail();
} 
catch (MessagingException e) {
    Log.e("mailReader getMail error. in readmail.java", e.getMessage(), e);
}



ArrayAdapter<Message> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(this,
R.layout.simple_list_item_1 ,messages){
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Message message = getItem(position);
        TextView resultView = new TextView(super.getContext());
        try {
            resultView.setText(message.getSubject());
        } 
        catch (MessagingException e) {
            Log.e("resultView.setText in readmail", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return resultView;
    }
};

setListAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

either invert the order of the array , or for the `getItem` , use the reverted index (count-position-1) .

btw, that's not an efficient way to use listviews , and in fact it has a memory leak which will cause it to crash after a lot of items (about 10000 is enough for SGS3) .

for more information about listView , check this video:

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total number of messages through `inbox.getMessageCount()`, then retrieve last N number of messages.

```
Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages(inbox.getMessageCount() - 25 , inbox.getMessageCount());
```