# Android Email information

Tags: android

I have found many examples of sending emails by android application, but I need application that show subject of the last income email. I found [How to get the list of available folders in a mail account using JavaMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790844/how-to-get-the-list-of-available-folders-in-a-mail-account-using-java-mail) and this [Listing Inbox with Javamail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101615/listing-inbox-with-javamail-api), but when I launch my app I see "The application myApp has stoped unexpectedly".

Comment: And what shows logcat? Any stacktrace and/or code could be useful here.